# Apex controller action not accessible - "Unknown controller action 'getLeadSourceOptions'"

Tags: apex, controller, action

I'm up against a wall with this one. I've scrubbed my code 20+ times and I'm not seeing what I'm missing. According to the error, it sounds like the helper in the extended component is calling the apex action correctly, but the apex action isn't found.

This component is going to be used (eventually) to embed as a lightning out component on our external website in place of the Web2Lead process.

## DataComponentHelper.js

```
({
    callServer : function(component,method,callback,params) {

        var compEvent1 = component.getEvent("loading");
        compEvent1.fire(); 

        var action = component.get(method);
        if (params) {
            action.setParams(params);
        }

        action.setCallback(this,function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") { 
                // pass returned value to callback function
                callback.call(this,response.getReturnValue());   
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                // generic error handler
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    console.log("Errors", errors);
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        throw new Error("Error" + errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Error("Unknown Error");
                }
            }
            var compEvent2 = component.getEvent("doneloading");
            compEvent2.fire(); 
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

## DataComponentHelper.js

```
<aura:component abstract="true">

    <aura:registerEvent name="loading" 
                        type="c:loading"/>

    <aura:registerEvent name="doneloading" 
                        type="c:doneloading"/>

    {!v.body} 
</aura:component>
```

## Web2LeadCmp.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="Web2LeadController" extends="c:DataComponent" >

    <!-- ATTRIBUTES -->
    <aura:attribute name="firstName" type="String" default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="lastName" type="String" default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="company" type="String" default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="email" type="String" default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="title" type="String" default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="phone" type="String" default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="interestOptions" type="String[]" default="" />

    <!-- HANDLE EVENTS -->
    <!--<aura:method name="refresh" action="{!c.doInit}" access="PUBLIC" description="Re-invokes doInit() method" />-->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <!-- FORM -->
    <form class="slds-form--stacked">
        <lightning:input label="First Name" name="firstName" value="{!firstName}" />
        <lightning:input label="Last Name" name="lastName" value="{!lastName}" />
        <lightning:input label="Company" name="company" value="{!company}" />
        <lightning:input type="email" label="Email" name="email" value="{!email}" />
        <lightning:input label="Phone" name="phone" value="{!phone}" />
        <lightning:input type="tel" label="Phone" name="phone" value="{!phone}" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"/>
        <ui:menu >
            <ui:menuTriggerLink aura:id="checkboxMenuLabel" label="Multiple selection"/>
            <ui:menuList aura:id="checkboxMenu" class="checkboxMenu">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.interestOptions}" var="o">
                    <ui:checkboxMenuItem label="{!o}"/>
                </aura:iteration>
            </ui:menuList>
        </ui:menu>
    </form>

</aura:component>
```

## Web2LeadCmpController.js

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {

        helper.callServer(
            component,
            "c.getLeadSourceOptions",
            function(response) {

                component.set("v.interestOptions", response);  

            }
        );
    }
})
```

## Web2LeadController.apxc

```
public with sharing class Web2LeadController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<String> getLeadSourceOptions(){

        List<String> options = new List<String>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Lead.LeadSource.getDescribe();

        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

        for(Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
        {
            options.add(f.getValue());
        }
        return options; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `callServer` method defined, it should be in `Web2LeadCmpHelper.js` instead of being in different component's helper `DataComponentHelper.js`

Comment: Rahul - Technically, I should be able to extend another component and thereby use it's helper. However, there is a small nugget of information that I failed go gain in my Salesforce 601 class.

Wrong Way
<aura:component abstract="true">
...

Right Way
<aura:component extensible="true" abstract="true">
...

Comment: A work-around may be to pass the action i.e. `component.get("c.getLeadSourceOptions")` from the `Web2LeadCmpController ` that can lookup the server-side method back into the `DataComponentHelper` that cannot.

Comment: SOLVED
See my response to Rahul above. Thank you for the help guys! I thought it might be something simple.

Here is the resource I ended up using to find my mistake:
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/03/salesforce-lightning-components-by-example-component-extension.html